# What is the Difference Between An Immediate Signing Certificate and an Intermediate Certificate?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, certificate, elastic-beanstalk

I am doing some work with AWS, and in the process of uploading my certificate to AWS, the certificate chain I am uploading is throwing an error that says,

> The certificate chain must start with the immediate signing
>   certificate, followed by any intermediaries in order

My question is: **what is the difference between immediate and intermediate in this context?** I have searched all over the web and everyone explains what an intermediate is, but I can't find something specific on the what exactly the immediate is supposed to be in this context.

I saw this answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/643605/openssl-determining-the-immediate-signing-certificate) but they don't explain what intermediate/immediate are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a really misleading way of saying "the end entity certificate" -- that is, the certificate that was issued to you and which validates the identity of the service you're running.

Comment: So... my public certificate then?

Comment: Yep, that'll be the one.